# How do I make an animation play only if the player isn't moving in Roblox Studio

Tags: roblox-studio

My animation is playing while the character runs and it gets in the way of the running animation so I just want the player to be able to punch while the character isn't running.

```
local RS = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')
local clickEvent = RS.ClickEvent
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local animator = humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")

local punchAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
punchAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://16008390781"
local punchAnimationTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(punchAnimation)

while wait(1) do
    if (humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude <= 0) then
        mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function(plr)
            for i,v in pairs(player.Character.Humanoid:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
                v:Stop()
            end
            clickEvent:FireServer(plr)
            punchAnimationTrack:Play()
        end)
    end
end
```

I check if the player is stood still and I have used a print method which proves that, yet somehow the mouse going down is still detected while the player is moving